# line integrals of vector fields with respect to y

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I just need guideline how to find the integral. $\vec{\mathbf{F}} = yx \hat{i} + 2 \hat{j} + x\hat{k}$, parametrised by $x = ct$, $y = c/t$ and $z = d$ for range $0 \leq t \leq 2$. Evaluate $\int \vec{\mathbf{F}}dy$. I need help setting up the integral.